# AWS ALB unhealthy target after rolling update of deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, amazon-alb

I have a EKS cluster with the [aws-alb-ingress-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/) controlling the setup of the AWS ALB pointing to the EKS cluster.

After a rolling update of one of the deployments, the application failed, causing the `Pod` to never start (The pod is stuck in status `CrashLoopBackOff`). However the previous version of the `Pod` is still running. But it seems like the status of the service is still unhealthy:

[image]

This means now all traffic is redirected to the default backend, a different service. In this case in Kubernetes the related service for the deployment is of type `NodePort`:

```
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       172.20.186.130
Port:                     http-service  80/TCP
TargetPort:               5000/TCP
NodePort:                 http-service  31692/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.3.55:5000
```

What is causing the endpoint to become unhealthy? I expected it to just redirect traffic to the old version of the `Pod` that is still running. Is there any way were I can ensure that the endpoint remains healthy?

Comment: Can you verify by "kubectl get endpoints SVC" what pods are now targeted by service?

Comment: It seems to be pointing to the healthy pod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that while in Kubernetes the application was healthy, the ALB load-balancer performed it's own health check. This health check was configured by default to expect a `200` response from the `/` endpoint, however for this specific application it did not return a `200` response on that endpoint.

Since the ALB is controlled by the alb-ingress-controller, I added an annotation on my ingress to configure the correct path: `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path:  /health`. Since we are working with Spring Microservices this endpoint works for all our applications.

Comment: If this solution worked for you please mark it as accepted, to make it easier for the community to find a solution.

Comment: An addition to this answer - if you need different healthcheck settings (path, expected status, etc) for each of your apps, you can add corresponding annotations to the k8s Service of that app.